# Rotated parabola 2d vertex

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, conic-sections

I'm implementing an application where I need to get the vertex of a parabola, the parabola might be tilted; so it can have an angle with the x-axis not necessarily vertical or horizontal.
Can I get the vertex value from 3 points on the parabola?

Answer (score 1):

No.

When we know the parabola' axis is vertical, it takes three points to define a parabola. (See the Lagrange interpolation formula: three points define a 2nd-degree polynomial, which defines a parabola.) Allowing the axis to rotate adds another degree of freedom, so three points are no longer sufficient. Given any three points we can find a parabola in *any* direction (at least, those where the points are not all in a vertical or horizontal line), so the parabola is not well defined if we allow all directions.

[Four points determine a parabola up to a choice of two possibilities](https://web.archive.org/web/20171124184026/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53228.html).